# What kind should be my variable in order to support small numbers?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
return 1.0 / (1 + exp(-x));
```

It is used to calculate the value of a sigmoid function for a given x. The problem is that it always returns 1.00000

I started going through the code to see where it fails and I got to this:

```
long double expV = exp(-x);
long double btm = (1 + expV);
long double calc = 1.0 / btw;
```

Now the values of the variables are:

```
(long double) expV = 3.0356148105583944943E-165
(long double) btm = 1
(long double) calc = 1
```

So my question is how to fix the problem should I use another type for the variables or should I change something in the code?

Update btm should be of value: 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030356148105583944943 as WolframAplha said

The value of x is 1 and x is of type double not long double. I change it to long double and report.

Comment: What is the value of x? What result do you expect? - Your result is not a small number but so close to one that it is equal to one within the precision of a `double`.

Comment: how is x declared? Is it a `long double' too?

Comment: x is of type double. The value of x is 1 but that shouldn't matter because exp requires a double and returns a double. I also tried everything to be double at first.

Comment: If x is 1 then exp(-x) should be 0.367..., so there must be something wrong in your calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the precision of the long double isn't sufficient to cope with such a small addition (in the case of `btm`). The '1' outweighs the tiny `expV` and thus, within the precision of the long double, `btm` is merely 1.

In answer to your question, your code is fine: logically there is nothing wrong, you just need a more precise data type. Unfortunately, Objective-C doesn't provide one [(some discussion here about arbitrary precision in Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205740/arbitrary-precision-bit-manipulation-objective-c). However, if you're willing to go a little further afield, [the GNU MP library](http://gmplib.org) (and others) will be able to help you out with arbitrary precision mathematics. Of course, arbitrary precision maths comes at a performance cost - there's no such thing as a free lunch, sadly.

Comment: What should I use fix the problem? The values are small enough to not care about that much about the precision at this point. Should I just round them up and if so what will be the best way?

Comment: It depends on whether you actually need that much precision or not. If you use an arbitrary-precision library, your values will be computed as the value you've shown from WolframAlpha - that WILL be the number evaluated, exactly. Your return value will thus become a type from inside the arbitrary-precision library, not a `long double`. As to whether you round your values, it again depends on what precision you want from your final answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Sorry, the exponent support in NSDecimalNumber is from -128 to 127 so wouldnt work in this particular case but otherwise it is good for fixed point arithmetic calculations

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**
 [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDecimalNumber* expV = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:3.0356148105583944943
                                          exponent:-165
                                          isNegative:NO];
NSDecimalNumber* k = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2.0"];

NSDecimalNumber* btm = [expV decimalNumberByAdding:k];

NSDecimalNumber* calc = [k decimalNumberByDividingBy:btm];
```

may not be the most elegant way to do it :/

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has 38 significant digits, that is not enough for this calculation.

Comment: @MartinR you'r right. Just checked. the exponent support is from -128 to 127. Didnt realize the exponent here was so large.